# Concourse: cannot access job resources during put step

Tags: docker, concourse

I am trying to have a job create and push a docker image that contains my application's dependencies using the build parameter. In the concourse docs it states that all resources that have been fetched via `get` are available during a put step. I don't seem to be able to access my git resource however in order to pull the pom.xml file from it. When I try to run this job I get an error that pom.xml file does not exist.

## pipeline job

```
  - name: get-dependencies
    plan:
    - get: git-repo
      passed: [pull-repo]
      trigger: true
    - get: artifacts-container
    - put: artifacts-container
      params:
        inputs: [git-repo]
        build: git-repo/app/concourse/dockerfiles/artifacts
```

## Dockerfile

```
# Set base image qualities
FROM localhost:5000/app-artifacts:0.0.3 AS build

Load application into image
COPY git-repo/app/pom.xml /

RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
```

Comment: Could it be a relative path issue? That is, the Dockerfile being build is on "git-repo/app/concourse/dockerfiles/artifacts" and trying to access something from "git-repo/app/pom.xml". Maybe it's looking for "git-repo/app/pom.xml inside "git-repo/app/concourse/dockerfiles/artifacts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar Problem. I wanted to build a docker image and put a folder from a different resource into that image using the COPY Command.

First i gave the docker-image-resource only the "build" parameter with the folder where the Dockerfile lives. But that way i was unable to access the other-resource I ended up using a both the 'build' and the 'dockerfile' parameter. That way the build happens in the root of the put step and all other artefacts are available.

My Pipeline:

```
- put: docker-image-resource
  params:
    build: .
    dockerfile: ./path/to/Dockerfile
    build_args:
      CONFIG_DIR: ./other-resource/
```

I have furhter used a build-arg to decouple the Dockerfile from the pipelines build. So i can be able to pecify other directories in other build context (e.g. local).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your container does, but you should remove the `- get: artifacts-container` statement and just leave the `put`.